# Change Docker (snap) data-root folder

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to change the default data folder of docker images, containers, etc to a different path. Snap installation of docker has such folder at `/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker`.
Theoretically I could change that with `data-root` option in `deamon.json`. But, if I change the `daemon.json` adding `"data-root": "/home/user/docker"` docker won't start due to a conflict with flags (which always has the previously described default path on it).

I do can start docker with my custom path if I stop it and then start it like this: `sudo snap start docker.dockerd --data-root=/home/user/docker`. Which is not pretty but works. Is there a way to change docker snap flags on startup or make it prefers the daemon.json options?

I've read [this](https://github.com/docker-archive/docker-snap/issues/22) archived post, which treats such issue on docker version 17, but it didn't helped much the same way several other material I found online. I seems that symbolic link may be a way tho...

I'm using docker 19.03.11, snap installed on Ubuntu 20.04.

P.s.: The new path is on a second HDD mounted as my home directory. Changing the path will save space in my system SSD.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Try moving the data and create a symlink. If not then you may want to explore `/etc/docker/daemon.json` where you can set the new location.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: From my experience, any attempt to change this results in docker being unable to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/docker-snap/docker-snap/issues/3 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/550348/how-to-make-mount-bind-permanent, the not-perfect-but-working solution seems to be **the bind mount** between **/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker** and **/home/username/docker** which is the previous docker data-root I had before installing docker with snap.

So first, clear the data-root option in **daemon.json**.

Then add the following at the end of **/etc/fstab** with the following command:

```sh
echo '/home/username/docker /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker none bind' >> /etc/fstab
```

After reboot, your docker data root will be stored in **/home/username/docker**

Comment: what does this do to the old /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker contents? should I be concerned?

Comment: when the target folder starts blank, I end up with ```Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info```

Comment: I don't think you should be concerned of the old docker directory, It's a bit like having two docker environnements.

Comment: why not use a symbolic link? wouldn't `ln -s /newfolder /var/snap/docker/common` work?

Answer (score 1):

I ran out of space on an Ubuntu VirtualBox VM and had to do the following:

1. Stop the VM and create a new Fixed Volume
2. Start the VM and make sure the new volume was mounted
3. Stop the docker service

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop docker.service
   sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
   ```
4. Copy `/var/lib/docker` to new volume

   ```
   sudo rsync -aqxP /var/lib/docker/ /media/username/spare\ disk/
   ```
5. Update `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

   ```
   {
       "data-root": "/media/username/spare disk/docker",
       "storage-driver": "overlay2"
   }
   ```
6. Reload systemd and start docker service

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl start docker
   ```

See: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#runtime-directory-and-storage-driver